# Tooltips for wxAuiNoteBook Tabs?

Tags: wxwidgets

I find it difficult to control detailed behavior of wxwidgets auinotebooks.

There seems no "SetTabToolTip" method for any tab (not the page).

Setting the tooltip for the whole notebook doesn't work for tabs.

After several days of googling, no valuable result found... Any hint?

Comment: A good place to look for these sorts of questions is in the samples directory of your wxWidgets installation. Have you looked at the aui example, specifically? Sometimes the best way to find out about an undocumented feature is to check the samples.

Comment: Yes, I checked the sample before I googled. I also looked into the source code carefully to find a method or macro which may help doing the job. It seems getting the children of the book may help, but would be rather ugly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This functionality has been added in more recent version of wx, you can now call [`SetPageToolTip()`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_aui_notebook.html#aed55320cf754f5f6b8fffa1240dd749b) on the wxAuiNotebook.